# Broken links pointing to sharepointoverflow.com

Tags: feature-request

I have noticed several broken links in SP.SE, such as the broken link in this question: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/1099/2688

I believe the reason they are broken is because they point to the old SP.SE address: http://www.sharepointoverflow.com

To fix the problem, is it possible to replace all "www.sharepointoverflow.com" with "www.sharepoint.stackexchange.com"?

Comment: Doing a search, there looks to be only 3 questions with sharepointoverflow.com: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22sharepointoverflow.com%22 - this assumes search is including links correctly

Comment: Incidentally, the search doesn't return the above question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may require manual editing, unfortunately. I am not aware of an automated way of doing this.

Comment: Isn't Stack Exchange data all stored in a SQL Server Database? Can we get a SE moderator to do a mass-replace for us perhaps?

Comment: I think that would be a big ask.